# SwiftUI How to make circular animation work in both direction

Tags: animation, swiftui, transition

I have such custom circular animation and I want to make it showing from center off screen and then hiding it to center of screen. 
Now it works one way or other but not both.

```
return AnyTransition.asymmetric(
            insertion: AnyTransition.modifier(
                active: ClipShapeModifier(shape: ScalableCircle(percent: 0).offset(offset)),
                identity: ClipShapeModifier(shape: ScalableCircle(percent: 1).offset(offset))
            ),
            removal: AnyTransition.modifier(
                active: ClipShapeModifier(shape: ScalableCircle(percent: 1).offset(offset)),
                identity: ClipShapeModifier(shape: ScalableCircle(percent: 0).offset(offset))
            )
        )
```

and here I am showing/hiding view

```
if showOnboarding {
            OnboardingView()
     .transition(.circularReveal())
 } else {
                    ContentView()
  }
```

If I apply only insertion then it works ok show FROM center. 
If I apply only removal then it works ok hide TO center. 
But then other way doesn't work correctly. There is rather opacity transition.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution

1. It is needed regular transition to asymetric as this is the same (only reverted) transition . So

   ```
    return AnyTransition.modifier(
               active: ClipShapeModifier(shape: ScalableCircle(percent: 0).offset(offset)),
               identity: ClipShapeModifier(shape: ScalableCircle(percent: 1).offset(offset))
           )
   ```
2. it is important to apply .zIndex(1) to transitioning view cause while hiding it is going beneath new appearing view with changing opacity

   ZStack {

   ```
           if showOnboarding {
               OnboardingView()

                   .transition(.circularReveal())
                   .zIndex(1)
           } else {
               ContentView()
           }

       }
   ```